# Why does junit say my boolean test should be void?

Tags: java, junit, boolean

I've searched on google and clicked link after link on many different sites and none of the available answers helped me.  This is unfortunate since some of the sites reference the same answer, which I wasn't able to make fit my problem.  That link was ([Junit testing for a boolean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119392/junit-testing-for-a-boolean-method))...

The output from trying to run the test is: "method testAddObject() should be void."  The actual method is a boolean method and if I set the test up as void, I get a different error.  I can't just arbitrarily make it void.

I'll use code snippets.  First my code, and then my jUnit test.

Code:

```
public boolean add(Object ob) {
    boolean isSuccessful = true;

    /**
     * if array is full, get new array of double size,
     * and copy items from old array to new array
     */
    if (isFull()) 
    {
        expandArray();
    } 
    else if (!isFull())
    {
        // add new item; update numItems
        items[numItems] = ob;
        numItems++;         
    }
    else
        isSuccessful = false;

    return isSuccessful;            
} // end add
```

JUNIT TEST:

```
@Test
public boolean testAddObject() {
    boolean result = true;
    boolean ans;
    AList arraylist = new AList(3);
    arraylist.add("apple");
    arraylist.add("pear");
    ans = arraylist.add("melon");
    return ans == result;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

All JUnit test methods should be void. It's in the test assertions that confirms if your code is producing the intended output. For your scenario, the `assertTrue` method will check if the output of your method returns `true`.

There are other types of assertions such as `assertEquals` and `assertFalse`. For more information of the different types of assertions, check the [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html).

So you can modify your test case like this

```
@Test
public void testAddObject() {
    boolean ans;
    AList arraylist = new AList(3);
    arraylist.add("apple");
    arraylist.add("pear");
    ans = arraylist.add("melon");

    assertTrue(ans);
}
```

where `assertTrue` checks that ans is a boolean with a value of `true`

Answer (score 3):

JUnit methods can't have a return type, so you test for success with the following:

```
@Test
public void testAddObject() {
//Your data setup and invocation of the add method
assertTrue(ans == result);
}
```

There are tons of assertion options if you want more than True/False, they can be found here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use assert method to check for your test method add(object).
**assertEquals(expected result, actual result)**
There are many variations of assert method.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit calls internally `validateTestMethods` from its `org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator` class, and verifies e.g., if the return type is `Void.TYPE`:

```
if (each.getReturnType() != Void.TYPE)
    fErrors.add(new Exception("Method " + each.getName() + " should be void"));
```

Therefore you have to use *void* as return type.

Comment: Thanks. This is great explanation that is why Junit test must has to be void. 
Yes we can change it using  assetTrue etc to check boolean.
But the question which always came in my mind is why Junit only allows void return type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Your Test method should like follows

```
@Test
public void testAddObject() {
  // inside this method you should test add() method
  // create input object(Object obj=new Object())
  // create a instance of the class which has add()
  // call add() method with obj
  // validate return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the way JUnit works is by calling those methods. Those methods will give JUnit attention (marked as RED/Failed) if:

- Exceptions happens (of course)
- One of assertations is failed e.g. assertEquals("expected text", "factual text as result of your program")

Answer (score 0):

JUnit test method must be void as return type.

Please assertXXX to test result.